# array.sort() в microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, браузер, microsoft-edge

Есть следующий код:

```
    var mas = [1,2,3,4,5];
    mas = mas.sort(function(){
        return Math.random() > 0.5;
    })
    console.log(mas);
```

В хроме код выдает случайно перемешанный массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В microsoft edge массив не меняется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить microsoft edge работать с js как в хроме? Ну или хотя бы этот кусочек кода.

Comment: Никак. И не строить логику своего кода на знании (или угадывании) того, как конкретный движок реализует спецификацию. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var mas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
mas = mas.sort(function() {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
})
console.log(mas);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вообще то внутри sort return может быть отрицательным (< 0), положительным (> 0) и 0

```
sort(function(a, b){
    // если < 0 а идет первым
    // если > 0 b идет первым
    // 0 нечего не делаем
})
```

Хочу обратить внимание что ваш пример возвращает boolean, чего нет в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

И в хроме работает только потому что sort кастует boolean к int и получаеться что true == 1, false == 0.

А вот Осел этого не понимает потому и не работает.

Ответ @Igor более корректный если задача перемешать массив